# Was my RDD recomputed or did it pull from the cache?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, caching

How do I figure out if my RDDs had to be recomputed or if they pulled from the cache?

(I am trying to remove unnecessary cache statements and I am testing performance)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can approach this is to set the name of the RDDs that you want to know if they were cached, and check the Storage tab in the Spark UI.

From there you will be able to tell if they are cached or partially cached and may need to be recomputed.